# Django not returning proper object data in JsonResponse

Tags: json, django

I'm trying to return JSON data but it returns fields, model and pk.
Here is my code:

### project.py

```
def data_list_projects(request):

    user_id = request.session['user_id']
    if not user_id:
        return HttpResponse(JsonResponse({'message': 'not logged'}), content_type="application/json")

    projects = Project.objects.filter(status='active')

    if projects and len(projects) > 0:
        response_data = {'found': True, 'projects': serializers.serialize('json', projects), 'message': 'logged'}
    else:
        response_data = {'found': False, 'message': 'logged'}

    return JsonResponse(response_data, content_type="application/json")
```

### list.js

```
$(function(){

    getProjects();
});

function getProjects(){

    $.ajax({
        url: root + 'data-list-projects',
        type: 'get',
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(result){
             console.log(result);
        }
    });
}
```

When I check the response on Google Chrome, I get:

```
{"found": true, "message": "logged", "projects": "[{"fields": {"status": "active", "created_at": "2015-08-20T10:08:46Z", "name": "a", "created_by": 1, "description": "b"}, "model": "app.project", "pk": 1}]"}
```

This was returned fine in Laravel and Rails. Why there is no data for project objects. I need the JSON response to be like this:

```
{"found": true, "projects":[{"id": "10", "name": "Project 1", "description": "Contain the bugs from Site.", "created_by": "4", "status": "active", "created_at": "2015-06-26 12:40:50", "updated_at": "2015-08-11 11:42:40"}], "message": "logged"}
```

Comment: I don't understand what you mean about missing data. But you are double-encoding the model data, because you're serializing to JSON, putting the result into a Python dict, then serializing the whole thing again. Instead, do `serializers.serialize('python', projects)`.

Comment: Thanks Neo for the quick reply. Actually I do not want model, pk and the "fields". The desired output I need is given in the thread.

Comment: Consider using django-rest-framework to create output that you're needed. Also, you're packing JsonResponse into HttpResponse in first return of your view, you shouldn't do that.